# pass argument for instance variable for class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subclass

how can I pass argument for class's instance variable like following, how can I pass *sclass* for Subclass when I initial ClassElement

```
class Subclass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg


class ClassElement(object):
    sclass = Subclass('sclass')

    def __init__(self, argA: str, argB: str):
        self.argA = argA
        self.argB = argB
tcl = ClassElement('argA', 'argB')
print(tcl.argA)
print(tcl.argB)
print(tcl.sclass)
print(tcl.sclass.arg)
```

Comment: Your `ClassElement` has no attribute `sclass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code defines sclass as *class variable*, and you're checking an *instance variable tcl.sclass.arg*. These are two different things; class variables and instance variables.

If you want to use the same object to every instance - use class variable.
If the object is unique to every instance - use instance variable.

Every instance has sclass:

```
class ClassElement(object):
    def __init__(self, argA, argB, sclass):
        self.argA = argA
        self.argB = argB
        self.sclass = Subclass(sclass)
```

---

All instances share single object (your code):

```
>>> ClassElement.sclass
<__main__.Subclass object at 0x02942BF0>
>>> ClassElement.sclass.arg
'sclass'

>>> tcl2 = ClassElement('argA', 'argB')
>>> id(tcl2.sclass)
43265008
>>> id(tcl.sclass)
43265008
```

---

Ok I think I understand now what you are looking for

```
class ClassElement(object):
    sclass = None

    def __init__(self, argA, argB, sclass):
        self.argA = argA
        self.argB = argB
        ClassElement.sclass = Subclass(sclass)
```

This will update the class variable with every instance creation.

Comment: hi, yes, I would like to use SUbclass as class variable but passing 'sclass' as argument when initial ClassElement...is it possible

Comment: I've edited my answer; you can accept additional parameter on ClassElement, and then pass it to your SubClass as argument.

Comment: but your answer is using Subclass as instance variable not using as class variable and assign now *arg* for sclass

Comment: So you want it to be a class or instance variable? If it's a class, once you change it - it is changed for all instances

Comment: yes, i try to create one @classmethod to update it, it seems like without include on `def __init__`, but it does nto work after include in def __init__

Answer (score 0):

```
class Subclass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg


class ClassElement(object):
    def __init__(self, argA, argB):
        self.argA = argA
        self.argB = argB
        self.sclass = Subclass('sclass')

tcl = ClassElement('argA', 'argB')

print(tcl.argA)
print(tcl.argB)
print(tcl.sclass)
print(tcl.sclass.arg)
```